# Concat String and php Variable when appending in html

Tags: php, html, string-concatenation

I have used below code:

```
$html = '';
$html. = '<br></br>';
$html .= '<a href= "javascript:void(0)" class= "test" onclick= "get_data($access_token,1,$marketTagId);">Next 50  </a>';
```

but my PHP variables are not recognized.

Comment: `get_data('.$access_token.',1,'.$marketTagId.');`

Comment: `$html .= "<a href= 'javascript:void(0)' class= 'test' onclick= 'get_data($access_token,1,$marketTagId);'>Next 50  </a>";` Need to learn about working of quotes in php

Comment: i have tried it but not working

Comment: yes tried it but not working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Difference between Double quotes and single quotes

According to [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php#answer-3446286):

1. [**Single quoted strings**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) will display things almost completely "as is." Variables and most escape sequences will not be interpreted. The exception is that to display a literal single quote, you can escape it with a back slash `\'`, and to display a back slash, you can escape it with another backslash `\\` (**So yes, even single quoted strings are parsed**).
2. [**Double quote strings**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) will display a host of escaped characters (including some regexes), and variables in the strings will be evaluated. An important point here is that **you can use curly braces to isolate the name of the variable you want evaluated**. For example let's say you have the variable `$type` and you what to `echo "The $types are"` That will look for the variable `$types`. To get around this use `echo "The {$type}s are"` You can put the left brace before or after the dollar sign. Take a look at [string parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) to see how to use array variables and such.

## Solution

They are not recognized, because you have put all your string in single quotes (`'`).

You should replace them all with double quotes (`"`).

```
$html = "";
$html. = "<br></br>";
$html .= "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"test\" onclick=\"get_data('$access_token',1,'$marketTagId');\">Next 50</a>";
```

## Another solution

Also you have the option of separating your variables from text:

```
$html = '';
$html. = '<br></br>';
$html .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="test" onclick="get_data("' . $access_token . '",1,"' . $marketTagId . '");">Next 50</a>';
```

## Yet another solution

If you don't want to escape so many double quotes, you may use single quotes instead:

```
$html = "";
$html. = "<br></br>";
$html .= "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='test' onclick='get_data(\"$access_token\",1,\"$marketTagId\");'>Next 50</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might help you

```
<?php

$html = '';
$html. = '<br></br>';
$html .= '<a href= "javascript:void(0)" class= "test" onclick= "get_data($access_token,1,'.$marketTagId.');">Next 50</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
get_data('".$access_token."',1,'".$marketTagId."');
```

Or

```
 get_data(<?php $access_token ?>,1,<?php $marketTagId ?> );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `''` around your PHP variables otherwise in `onclick` function they will not worked.

Use below code:-

```
$html = '';
$html. = '<br></br>';
$html .= "<a href= 'javascript:void(0)' class= 'test' onclick= \"get_data('$access_token','1','$marketTagId');\">Next 50  </a>";
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This is not exact solution but i got idea from this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the php variables within `{` and `}`

```
$access_token = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$marketTagId = "__AAA__B_123";

$html = "";
$html .= "<br></br>";
$html .= "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"test\" onclick=\"get_data('{$access_token}',1, '{$marketTagId}')\">Next 50</a>";

echo htmlentities($html);
```

Comment: Went to [phpfiddle-cli](http://phpfiddle.org/clirun), paste the code below and hit F9 key, I get this; `<br></br><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="test" onclick="get_data('1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',1, '__AAA__B_123')">Next 50</a>`

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
$html. = '<br></br>'; 
$html .= '<a href= "
```

change to this:

```
$html.= '<br></br>'; 
$html.= '<a href= "
```

try this:

```
$html = '';
$html.= '<br></br>';
$html.= '<a href= "javascript:void(0)" class= "test" onclick= "get_data($access_token,1,$marketTagId);">Next 50  </a>';
```

can you expect this:[image]

Comment: But i need every php variables in single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Hi All Thanks for helping.
This is worked for me :

```
  $html .= '</table>';
    $html .= '<br><br>';
    $html .= '<a href= "javascript:void(0)" class= "test" onclick= \'get_data("'.$access_token.'","1","'.$marketTagId.'");\'>Next 50  </a>';
```

Comment: According to your [profile information](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5376298/rk1212) with bunch of answers, I don't think so, by the way you R welcome